# React обновление state объекта после изменения состояния input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, объекты, рекурсия, state

Мне нужен совет по работе с большим объектом!
Пример:

```js
const [myObject, setMyObject] = React.useState({
  next_step: {
    id: 1575567015473,
    block_type: 'message',
    position: 'bottom',
    message: 'lorem ipsum',
    actions: {
      id: 1575562323,
      type: 'step_action',
      title: 'Show answers',
      description: 'Resend answer to another user',
      method: 'show_answer',
      points: 30
    },
    waiting: {
    interval: '4h50m',
    id: 1,
    position: 'right,
    next_step: {
      id: 3,
      position: 'bottom',
      block_type: 'message',
      message: 'lorem ipsum 3',
      waiting: null,
      next_step: null
    }
    }
    next_step: {
      id: 2,
      position: 'bottom',
      block_type: 'message',
      message: 'lorem ipsum 2',
      waiting: null,
      next_step: {
          id: 4,
          position: 'bottom',
          block_type: 'message',
          message: 'lorem ipsum 4',
          waiting: null,
          next_step: null
        }
      }
  }

});
```

я использую рекурсию, для того что бы вывести содержимое объекта - message в input
Вопрос правильно ли, то что я буду при каждом изменение input делать рекурсию для поиска и изменения необходимого поля или стоит разделить объект на части и работать с каждым отдельно ?
Пример как сейчас реализовал:

```js
const findObject = (id, obj, fn) => {
  if (obj.id === id) {
    return fn(obj);
  }

  if (obj.waiting && obj.waiting.id) findObject(id, obj.waiting, fn);
  if (obj.next_step && obj.next_step.id) findObject(id, obj.next_step, fn);
  return obj;
};
  
const inputHandler = (value, id) => {
  const strFlowData = JSON.stringify(myObject);
  const newFlowData = JSON.parse(strFlowData);

  const inputUpdate = newObj => {
    const slackBlocks = newObj.body.blocks;
    const slackMassage = slackBlocks[0].text;
    slackMassage.text = value;
    return null;
  };

  findObject(id, newFlowData.next_step, newObj => inputUpdate(newObj));
  setMyObject(newFlowData);
};
```

Сейчас работает все хорошо, но если данный объект будет становиться все больше, не будет ли далее у меня проблем с обновлением данного объекта при изменении input?

Comment: Смотря как часто вы его меняете и насколько большим он будет. Лучше расскажите зачем вам такой объект и как вы его используете.

Comment: Это объект присылается с бека, ui будет примерно такое -  https://prnt.sc/q7ubdx , в каждом блоке я смогу менять текст, удалить , добавить блок. Этот объект может быть очень большим

Comment: Ну пока цель данного мероприятия всё ещё непонятна :) Если блок будет пересчитывать раз в пару секунд в одном компоненте, то никаких проблем не будет.

Comment: )) Делов в том что объект будет вызваться на каждое изменение input - <input  onChange={inputHandler} />.

Comment: Если вы опишите, что вы хотите сделать в конечном итоге, то будет понятнее.

Comment: Я уже сделал, но есть сомнения в правильности))  может есть более лучшее решение. Что необходимо было -  из объекта next_step брать поле message и вставлять его в новый блок с input. таких input будет столько сколько и next_step в объекте, схему я показал на скриншоте https://prnt.sc/q7ubdx, получается каждый темно зеленый блок - это next_step message, который я могу менять. На onChange я повесил inputHandler в котором происходит рекурсия findObject. Сейчас все работает хорошо, но вопрос в производительности и в правильности такого решения. Спасибо)))

Comment: Я имел ввиду более верхнеуровневое описание, что пользователь вводит, что нужно отобразить и зачем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101948/discussion-between-rtw-and-aleksey).